# How to move all files from one directory to another whose Last modified date was less than today

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I  want to move all files from one directory to another whose last modified date was earlier than today. Suppose today is 11-09-2013, then i want to move all files whose last modified date was 10-09-2013 and before.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using the find command

find . -newermt "2013-09-11 00:00:00"

or in your case (for between)

find . -newermt "2000-01-01 00:00:00" ! -newermt "2013-09-11 00:00:00"